# How to pass variables for the Android C/C++ NDK from Android to C

Tags: android, android-ndk

Having a variable in Java, how can one assign that variable from C? I have tried passing the variable as a parameter to the function, but I don't know how to do that.
Here is what I tried:
in the Java code:

```
String test = "";
stringFromJNI(test);
```

in the C code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_mduneau_compass3_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
    JNIEnv* env,
    jobject obj, /* this */
    jstring test) {
//std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
//return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
test="HI WORLD";
}
```

This gives an "Unexpected parameter declaration." error.

Comment: How does the generated header file look like? The function implementation must match the declaration in the header file. Looking at the call above, the return code might be void instead of jstring.

Comment: Why have you commented out the correct code in your c function? It correctly creates a new string and returns it. String instances are immutable so you can not change it even if the code is executed in JNI.

Comment: @Robert I am trying to change the variable from inside the C code, that's why. I am trying to assign multiple variables from the C code.

Comment: Changing a String variable is not allowed in Java. You could modify the memory region that belongs to the characters of the String (replacing it with a different string of the same length) but for doing so you would have to find the String data in memory. And be aware that the JVM can at any time move the String data to a different address, e.g. when the garbage collector reorganizes everything. To find the memory position you may need to parse the JVM internal structures.

Comment: What about an integer?

Comment: So, using this link https://medium.com/vorm/android-ndk-passing-complex-data-not-so-scary-anymore-fff1123537c6, I was able to pass a class to C and then change the class members, be them strings or integers.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to implement it.

1. Write a function in C that return the value which you want to assign to your variable in Java side. something like this

```java
String test = stringFromJNI(); // stringFromJNI returns a String
```

2. Write a function in Java side and call it in C and pass your value as argument.

```java
public void myNewValue (String str) {
    // str is here. you can assign it to other variables
}
```

The code you shared is wrong because you cannot assign a new value to the arguments and expect the origin variable to change.

Comment: This, particularly the first, is the right answer.  I also want to point out that String test = "";
stringFromJNI(test); won't work even in Java.  Strings are immutable objects-  they cannot be changed once created.  And Java doesn't have references like C/C++ where you can pass in a string& and change it.  The only way to change a string in Java is to create a new String and overwrite the variable.